# ng-repeat with recursive attributes object

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently learning angularjs 1.5.0
I'm making a small sample with a complex json object, like this :

```
{
"Families":[
    {
        "Name": "A",
        "Age": 1,
        "Children": [
            {
                "Name": "B",
                "Age": 2,
                "Children":[
                    {
                        "Name": "C",
                        "Age": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "D",
                        "Age": 4
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "X",
        "Age": 5,
        "Children":[
            {
                "Name": "Y",
                "Age": 2
            },
            {
                "Name": "Z",
                "Age": 4
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

As you see, Families contains many members, each member has name, age and children. I want to list out this family tree , but one thing is difficult to me is : I don't know how many children can a member have therefore I don't know how to list them out by using ng-repeat.

Can anyone help me please ? 
Thank you so much,

Comment: http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

Comment: Here a modified fiddle in the example from Jordan.J.D's comment to show another layer of categories and how it recursively adds it: [http://jsfiddle.net/Lgosoxks/](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgosoxks/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For displaying recursive json data arrays, use recursive templates in views.
create a template like below

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="familyTree">
       {{ family .name}}
     <ul ng-if="family.children">
       <li ng-repeat="family in family.children" ng-include="'familyTree'">           
       </li>
     </ul>
   </script>
```

and use ng-repeat in view like this to render the view

```
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="family in families" ng-include="'familyTree'"></li>
   </ul>
```

sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/NP7P5/)

more [details](http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates)